# How to determine the probability the lamp is on

Tags: probability

Consider a simple experiment.

A turned off lamp periodically turns on with period $L$ time slots, then in any slot, say $t$, what is the probability of the lamp being on?

I think the answer is $1/L$. However, the simulation shows I am wrong. For example, $L=2$, the probability of on is 0.55, and off is 0.45.

Can anyone help me to figure out this?

Comment: All questions could be titled "Can anyone help me to figure out this?". You should consider using a more describing title.

Comment: Thank you for the tips.

Answer (score 1):

To answer this you also need the period. If the lamp is turned on an hour a day and if the lamp is turned out an hour a year is a huge difference.

If $P$ is the period and the lamp is turned on the time $L$ then the probability is $L/P$.

Also note that some techniques for simulation will probably yield a probability that differ from the theoretical probabilitity. The probability for deviation can also be calculated. So don't count on an exact match at least.

Comment: Thank you. By the way, what's the means of "period"? Dose it means the "a day" in your answer?

Comment: @Dave Yes, and $L$ is the time during that period that the lamp is turned on (that is "an hour" in the example of the first paragraph).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think you are right.